# Convert PNG data to JPG data and viceversa without using UIKit in Swift

Tags: swift

I was wondering if there is a possibility to get PNG data and convert it into JPG data without using UIKit. Something like that:

```
enum Format {
    case png
    case jpg
}

func convert(data: Data, to format: Format) -> Data? {
    switch format {
    case .png:
        return data.toJPG
    case .jpg:
        return data.toPNG
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can look into the ImageMagick library: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#iOS

Comment: What is it you want to do, run the code on another OS than iOS?

Comment: I want to have UIKit free class so It can be on my Core module (Clean code)

Comment: I am also seeing that if I use the UIImage approach when I covert a JPG to PNG I get 22MB worth of data when the JPG is Only 2MB

Comment: @ReimondHill This is expected considering that PNG has no compression options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your jpeg/png data and initialize a CGImage from it, create a jpeg or PNG destination image with it. Something like:

---

```
extension Data {
    var pngFromJPEG: Data? {
        guard
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: self as CFData),
            let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent),
            let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
            let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, "public.png" as CFString, 1, nil)
        else { return nil }
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage,nil)
        guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else { return nil }
        return mutableData as Data
    }
    func jpegFromPNG(compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1) -> Data? {
        guard
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: self as CFData),
            let cgImage = CGImage(pngDataProviderSource: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent),
            let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
            let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, "public.jpeg" as CFString, 1, nil)
        else { return nil }
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage,[kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: compressionQuality] as CFDictionary)
        guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else { return nil }
        return mutableData as Data
    }
}
```

---

```
let profileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "jpg")!
let jpegData = try! Data(contentsOf: profileURL)

if let pngData = jpegData.pngFromJPEG {
    let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    do {
        let destPNG = docs.appendingPathComponent("test.png")
        try pngData.write(to: destPNG)
        if let jpegData = pngData.jpegFromPNG() {
            let destJPEG = docs.appendingPathComponent("test.jpeg")
            try jpegData.write(to: destJPEG)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Working like a charm! that's the approach I wanted to follow

Comment: I lose GPS data when I do this, could I be missing something?

Comment: PNG doesn’t store any info. Not even the image orientation.